# SQLXMLBulk Load identify by attribute and node

Tags: xml, xsd

Just wondering if I could get some help trying to write a schema
I have the following node

```
>   <Persons>
>         <Person system="FirstName">Joe</category>
>         <Person system="Surname">Doe</category>
>         <Person system="Phone">123456</category>
>         <Person system="Phone">789123</category>
>       </Persons>
```

Ive tried this

```
<xsd:element Name="Persons" sql:isconstant="1">                                     
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" Name="Person">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:attribute Name="FirstName" 
                             Type="xsd:string"  
                             sql:field="PersonsFirstName" />
            </xsd:extension>
          </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

When I run this I get the following error

> A name contained an invalid character.

Any help or pointers would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any names that contain invalid characters in the fragment you show, which suggests that either

- the problem is somewhere else in your input

or that

- your schema processor is confused by the misspelling of `name` and `type` as `Name` and `Type` (XML is case sensitive, yes?) and its diagnostic message is ... not as helpful as you might have hoped.

[Added later] You will probably find it helpful to work on your schema documents in an editor with built-in knowledge of XSD structures; that helps prevent simple errors.  And it will be easier to help you if you provide a minimal but complete example that allows the problem to be reproduced.  (When I embed your element declaration in a schema document and correct the spelling of @name and @type, I don't get any errors about xsd:attribute.  Without a reproducible example, the Q/A format of Stack Overflow degenerates to a game of Twenty Questions, which is a lot more fun when played live.)

Looking at your schema fragment more carefully I notice that the XML structure you're defining doesn't match the structure of your input:  your schema defines an attribute named `FirstName`, but the input you show has no such attribute; the input has an attribute unhelpfully named `System`, which can take `FirstName` as a value.

If you want to match the input you show, you'll want declarations of something like the following form (I leave the management of the sql:* annotations to you; I have flattened the structure because deep nesting seems to harder for so many people to understand the schema, including me):

```
<xsd:element name="Persons">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="Person" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="Person">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="System" type="xsd:NCName"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

If on the other hand you really need the schema to specify how to map each element into a column (I'm guessing that's what your sql:field attribute is doing), you may find it easier if you make the XML element type names say more explicitly what they are.  If the XML looked like this:

```
<Persons>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
    <Surname>Doe</Surname>
    <Phone>123456</Phone>
    <Phone>789123</Phone>
  </Person>
  <!--* ... other Person records here *-->
</Persons>
```

then it would be a lot simpler to map each field into a distinct SQL field.

But I'm not familiar with the annotations in your schema, and I may have misunderstood their function.

Comment: I changed all to lower case i now get xsd:attribute' is not allowed in this contex. Thanks for the help.